# I can't get my program to print out a Leap year

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, boolean, conditional-statements

The last method I was trying to get it to print out my program can't seem to get it to do it. I don't know what to do. And I'm in an online class so there is no one I could really ask. My teacher takes three days to reply.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

public static void main(String[] args) {
displayInstructions();
int year = getYear();
isLeap(year);
}

public static void displayInstructions() {
    System.out.println("This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
}

public static int getYear() {
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
int year = reader.nextInt();
return year;
}

public static boolean isLeap(boolean year) {
    boolean isLeapYear = false;
    if (year % 4 == 0 && year != 100) {
        isLeap = true;

    }
    else {
        isLeap false;
    }



}
public static void displayResuls( boolean isLeap, boolean year) {
  if (isLeap)
  {
    System.out.println("Year" +year+" is a Leap Year.");
  }

  else {
  System.out.println("Year" +year+" is not a Leap Year");

  }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'year' supposed to be?  You're declaring it as an 'int', then trying to pass it as a boolean, then acting on it as an int again...? :-0

Answer (score 1):

You never call `displayResuls(isLeap(year), year)`.

Edit: also your declaration of displayResults is wrong, it should be `int year` instead of `boolean year`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isLeap` function should be like:

```
public static boolean isLeap(int year) {
    boolean isLeapYear = false;
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))) {
        isLeapYear = true;
    } else {
        isLeapYear = false;
    }
    return isLeapYear;
}
```

Main mistake I think in condition. It is more complicated than yours.
Correct one:

```
(year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
```

For example, 2000 - leap, but 2100 - not.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code rewritten. Just like others said, you never called `displayResuls` and there was some minor typos. Keep coding ;)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayInstructions();
        int year = getYear();
        boolean ans = isLeap(year);
        displayResuls(ans, year);
    }

    public static void displayInstructions() {
        System.out.println("This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
    }

    public static int getYear() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = reader.nextInt();
        return year;
    }

    public static boolean isLeap(int year) {

        boolean isLeapYear = false;

        if (((year % 4) == 0) && (year != 100)) {
            isLeapYear = true;
        } else {
            isLeapYear = false;
        }
        return isLeapYear;
    }

    public static void displayResuls(boolean isLeap, int year) {

        if (isLeap) {
            System.out.println("Year " + year + " is a Leap Year.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Year " + year + " is not a Leap Year");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes to your program and it works fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayInstructions();
        int year = getYear();
        System.out.println("Entered Year is "+isLeap(year));
    }

    public static void displayInstructions() {
        System.out.println("This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. "
                + "The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
    }

    public static int getYear() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = reader.nextInt();
        return year;
    }

    public static boolean isLeap(int year) {
        boolean isLeapYear = false;
        if (year%4 == 0 && year != 100) {
            return isLeapYear = true;

        }
        else {
            return isLeapYear = false;
        }
    }
```